# Google chart size issues on google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, charts, google-visualization, linechart

I have a size issue on google chrome my problem is when I write height and width in the option its load perfect but it skips the points values on Vaxis
When I remove the height and width from the option it shows points but loads very small on google chrome and then load perfectly after the hard refresh page.
Both graph screenshots attached.

Graph code

```
         var options = {
                        title: 'SKATTNING',
                        height: 500,
                        width: 1100,
                        vAxis: {title: 'poäng',
                      viewWindow:{
                      max:10,
                      min:0
                    }},
                 hAxis: {title: ''},
                 chartArea: {
                  left: 40,
                  right: 300,
                  width: 500,
              },
                        curveType: 'function',
                        legend: {position: 'right'},
                        pointSize: 6,
                    };
                    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));
                    chart.draw(data, options);
                }
```

[without height and width in option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFcmX.png)

[with height and width in option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8hua.png)

Comment: is the chart being drawn in a hidden container, then shown later? this will cause similar issues...

Comment: @WhiteHat yes that was the issue. its solved